# Mac OS in Windows 7 using Virtual PC

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, virtual-machine

Can I run Mac OS inside Windows 7 using Microsoft Virtual PC. now I am using Windows XP Mode inside Windows 7.

Comment: If I read this question right, you're asking to run Mac OS on non-Apple hardware, thus this question is off-topic.  We don't encourage users to violate the EULA here.  Thus, closing as off-topic.

Comment: @studiohack It might even be legal using Mac OS X Server on a Mac running Windows via Boot Camp. (I wouldn't count on it either though).

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, because vanilla Mac OS does not feature the necessary drivers and is protected against this kind of thing.